# Is there a good way to connect to a database without exposing credentials in Python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm making a python program which I would like to distribute. I would also like to have a MySQL database which would store usernames and hashed and salted passwords for each person that registers.
How would I go about connecting to the database without anyone being able to open the source code and look at the credentials to connect to the database?

Comment: You never put any credentials or configurations like this in the source code! you should out-source it in a separate configuration file and load it in runtime.

Comment: If your program needs to connect to the database then it _must_ have some kind of credential.  You could is to provide a user with limited privileges on the db: perhaps they can only access certain tables, and can only query/insert and update.  Or wrap the database server in another server application with its own login credentials, so your users log in to the server app but only the server app has direct access to the db.  Googling for "securing database credentials for desktop applications" will give you a lot to go on - this question has been asked before on various stackexchange sites.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks, do you think using python sockets would be a good way to wrap the database

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, you can store the credentials in a json file, using json python packpage and put the file name in `.gitignore`. So, whoever clones your repository will need to create the json file for the script to work, you can also create a `README.md` explaining how to do it